# no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I try to deploy a spring api-gateway app to GKE using jenkins and helm chart

for RoleBinding I have this manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-sa
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-cr
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: [ "services", "pods", "configmaps", "endpoints" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "watch", "list" ]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-rb
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: api-gateway-cr
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: api-gateway-sa
```

and have this command

`helm upgrade --install -f helm-values/values.stag.common.yaml -f helm-values/values.stag.secret.yaml -f helm-values/values.stag.yaml stag-api-gateway helm-api-gateway || build_error=true`

But I keep getting error this

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: current release manifest contains removed kubernetes api(s) for this kubernetes version and it is therefore unable to build the kubernetes objects for performing the diff. error from kubernetes: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"`

What I had done:

- Update kubernetes version in jenkins-slave node to 1.20
- make sure that all manifest using rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1

What can I do next?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the command `kubectl version` to check the version of Kubernetes you're using. Make sure that you are using the latest kubernetes and [Helm version](https://github.com/DNXLabs/terraform-aws-eks-cloudwatch-logs/issues/7#issuecomment-1143525388)  to support `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`.
2. Examine the `apiVersion` field in your manifest to confirm it supports RoleBinding and it corresponds to the version supported by your Kubernetes cluster.
3. The API version is different in the error and the manifest file,  Check whether you used the below command after updating the version in the manifest file.

> `Kubectl apply -f <file name>`

Refer to the following official docs [RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), [Deprecated API Migration Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#rbac-resources-v122) for more information